# Writing to an online .txt file without opening the file

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to create some sort of log system in an excel add-in im working on and so far the best way I can think of doing this is to collect event text together and then when excel attempts to close append this text to an online text file hosted on a team sharepoint. Not everyone will have the drive mapped locally so I want to ideally do this through the file URL and also not open the file as im adding the text.
So far I've managed to do this with a local file but cannot figure out how to do this with an online file through a URL. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub testThis1(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim strFile_Path As String

    strFile_Path = "C:/***" '<=a real address goes in here
    Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
    Write #1, "This Is my sample Text" & Now

Close #1
```

How can I go about taking this approach on a web hosted file rather than a local file? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does the text file look like?  You could try ADO & SQL??

Comment: Thanks Nathan, unfortunately the infrastructure is set in place and I wont be able to mess with anything so it has to be a file on the team sharepoint im afraid

Comment: I think that you can put the sharepoint path in for the file and connect using ADO.  https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding something about how HTTP works. "and also not open the file as im adding the text" makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Ill have a look into this now thank you

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I was thinking that it should be possible to access the txt file as a data source rather than as a file in which case it wouldnt be opened. I've done this with a csv file but not over a network connection so not sure if its possible. If that doesnt make sense could you please let me know why not or point me in the right direction to more info please?